# How do I manually parse NodeJS and discern required files

Tags: javascript, node.js

What would I use to find which resources are required by a NodeJS file?

For example, if I had a file called "file.js" containing this:

```
import x from './x';
const y = require('./y');

// Some more code
```

How do I parse that file and extract './x' and './y'?

**Why would you do this?**

I'm playing with the idea of an architectural tool. To do this, I want to know which files are being required by the targeted source code.

I know that Webpack follows this information when it creates bundles, so that it can stack the required files in an appropriate order in a single concatenated (well, minified) file.

I don't need to do the concatenation, but I want to find which files would be used.

When I find out which files are being used by which files, I plan to assist a user in organising them in an orderly manner (e.g. by pointing out circular dependencies).

Comment: Ideally, that should never be necessary. If you wrote file.js, you should've installed all modules required by the file, and if somebody else wrote file.js, they should've produced a module that has a package.json that again, lists all the dependencies. Why do you have to do this? Just making sure this isn't an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I've updated the post to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For trivial cases, you could try feeding the source to some [JS parser](http://esprima.org/) and search the AST for calls to `require()`; as long as `require()` is called with a string constant as a parameter, it shouldn't be hard to determine the dependencies. More complex situations could cause problems, though.